# DRF SOCIAL OAUTH 2 detail

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using drf_social_auth2 library
The problem is to get another access token from same refresh token.
I can't find the url to send refresh token to get fresh access token.
Also, I ca't find all customizable settings of this library.

Comment: Could help us help you with an example of what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I am using the library drf-social-oauth2==1.0.9 .In the documentation I don't seem to find mentioning hoe to get new access token @GaëtanGR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation itself on how to get refresh token :

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&refresh_token=<your_refresh_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/token
```

<client_id> and <client_secret> are the keys generated automatically. you can find in the model Application you created.

**Update :** @wagnerdelima (main maintainer of the library) said in the comment that you need to use the latest version of github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2, version 1.1.4. It has bug fixes etc. pypi.org/project/drf-social-oauth2

Comment: I tested it and whole new refresh token is generated with access token. Also, is the expiry time of tokens customizable?

Comment: Yes, the expiry time of tokens is customizable. I am the main maintainer of the library, btw. You can check this for further instructions: https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2/issues/85.

If you were the one who opened the issue, thank you. I completely forgot to add that to the documentation.

Comment: Hey guys, please use the latest version of https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2, version 1.1.4.
It has bug fixes etc.

https://pypi.org/project/drf-social-oauth2/

Comment: Thanks I have update my answer to highlight your comment @wagnerdelima